# ReviewBoard SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: ssl, review-board

When I try "rbt post" I get this error "ERROR: Could not reach the Review Board server at http://reviewboard.company.com/: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)"

Answer (score 0):

If it is an internal company FQDN, try to find out whether you requesting over a companies proxy. If so, please delete your proxy envs and try again